# C++ dynamic memory deallocation

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, mergesort, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm having trouble designing my code for a mergeSort function so that I don't lose any memory, but I'm currently stuck and segfaulting. Valgrind keeps pointing me in the direction of my dynamically allocated `tempArray`, but I don't see a problem there, and while there are pointers in use, that should be the only place where memory could leak. My code:

```
template <typename T>
T* Sorts<T>::mergeSort(T arr[], int size){

    int mid=size/2;
    T* left=arr+0;
    T* right=arr+mid;

    if(size==0 || size==1){ //sorted
        return arr;
    }
    T* tmp=merge(mergeSort(left, mid), mergeSort(right, size-mid), mid, size-mid);

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        arr[i]=tmp[i];
    }
} 

template <typename T>
T* Sorts<T>::merge(T* left, T* right, int sizeLeft, int sizeRight){
    T* tempArray=new T[sizeLeft+sizeRight];

    if(left<right){
        for(int i=0; i<sizeLeft; i++){
            tempArray[i]=left[i];
        }
        for(int j=sizeLeft; j<(sizeRight+sizeLeft); j++){
            tempArray[j]=right[j];      
        }
        for(int k=0; k<(sizeLeft+sizeRight); k++){
            left[k]=tempArray[k];
        }
    }else{
        for(int i=0; i<sizeRight; i++){
            tempArray[i]=right[i];
        }
        for(int j=sizeRight; j<(sizeRight+sizeLeft); j++){
            tempArray[j]=left[j];       
        }
        for(int k=0; k<(sizeLeft+sizeRight); k++){
            left[k]=tempArray[k];
        }
    }
    delete[] tempArray;
    return left;
}
```

Comment: If you used `vector`s you wouldn't be having this problem.

Comment: `for(int j=sizeLeft; j<sizeRight; j++){` what if `sizeLeft > sizeRight`?

Comment: Also what do you use as `T` for test? Primitive type, or some non-trivial class?

Comment: I've been using int types for the test run, and I forgot to change the line with `j<sizeRight`, thanks for pointing that out. It should be `j<(sizeRight+sizeLeft)` so that it fills the remainder of the `tempArray`. Editing that now.

Comment: Your `mergeSort` doesn't always return a value. This should have caused a compiler warning.

Comment: My compiler didn't catch that, thanks. I added that and the segfault is gone, so that solves my original problem, now I'm trying to fix the mistake of trying to overwrite the location of the `left` pointer, which is losing track of my values. Thanks everybody

Comment: what if `size` is not of the form `2^N` with `N` integer when you set `mid = size/2`?